# How to check if two paths is on the same mount point?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I need to move a file from one directory to another in the android filesystem. How can I programmatically check if the two paths is on the same mountpoint?

The reason I want to know this is because if they are, we need to copy the bits instead of using [File.rename(newPath)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)).

Examples when the paths is on different mountpoints:

- The user wants to move a file from the internal to external storage.
- The user wants to move a file from /sdcard/files to /sdcard/external_sd/files on a samsungdevice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to determine which filesystem a file resides on from within an Android app:

- get the file's canonical path by calling File.getCanonicalPath() on it.
- then get the list of currently mounted filesystems & their mount point paths from /proc/mounts
- and find which mount point path is the most complete string match for the canonical path of the file in question, this should give you the mount point / filesystem of the file.

Compare results from the two files.

Answer (score 5):

Call `File.rename`. If it succeeds, they're on the same mountpoint.

Comment: It's one way to go. But if it fails - it can be for other reasons than being on different mountpoints.

Comment: I doubt that matters. For whatever reason it fails, you'll pretty much want to do the same thing -- try to do the copy yourself and report error only if that fails.