# Check if 2 paths are on the same volume

Tags: android, kotlin, path, filesystems

I already have permission,

```xml
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

*And,* test written data to all volumes to ensure I've access to all volumes.
Now,
I have 2 paths I need to know if they're on the same volume.
How do I achieve this?

I've already seen this one [How to check if two paths is on the same mount point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111115/how-to-check-if-two-paths-is-on-the-same-mount-point)
, but the accepted answer is not correct, so I've opened a new question.

For example, files from different volumes on my phone,

```
/storage/emulated/0/b.txt
/mnt/media_rw/0X84-15XX/a.txt
/storage/9CXX-6BXX/c.txt
```

Comment: I've also tried using Path.fileStore, which gives Security Exception.

Comment: can you add an example using `if-else` what do you want to do?

Comment: Have you tried: `File file = new File("b.txt");
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();` ?

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13509822/6576302)

Comment: @C.F.G If both paths are on the same mount point (i.e same partition) I want to use one strategy to `move` else (different partition) use another strategy.

Comment: @C.F.G the link you provided does not touch the topic mentioned in OP.

Comment: @CyberAvater Can you not just split and compare both the path strings to see if they have the same parent directory? If you are asking for a string/path matching algorithm, let me know. If not, let me know that too.

Comment: same volume doesn't always means same parent folder. The files can be in different level of a volume. So, you'd need to know how much of the parent should be matched to be considered under same volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is a bit tricky to determine whether two paths are on the same volume in Android, especially given the variations between different devices, Android versions, and OEM modifications. Have you tried looking at the file system's stat information?

```
fun isSameVolume(path1: String, path2: String): Boolean {
return try {
    val stat1: StructStat = Os.stat(path1)
    val stat2: StructStat = Os.stat(path2)

    stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev
} catch (e: Exception) {
    false
}
```

}

Comment: Passed my basic tests. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to check a multi-partition device. Can you verify it'll work there too?
(i.e. A single pendrive with multiple partitions, so the same device but different volume, won't the st_dev be the same? making it incorrect for multi-partition devices?)

Comment: I've just tested this on a multi-partition device and it returns false there. So, this is exactly what I was looking for.